# Error in python code (TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found)

Tags: python, python-3.x

The error occurs at line 49 "fileSizeRemainingInBytes = os.path.getsize(inFile)"
inFile contains the file I want to gets size. From what I understood in the python documentation this should be correct. Can someone tell me what is the problem.

```
import sys, os

buffer = 1000

try:
#open file in binary mode for reading
    inFile = open(sys.argv[1],"rb")
    print "file name is: ", inFile.name

except IOError:
#check for IOExceptions
    print "Eror opening file"
    sys.exit()

else:
#create new directory for copying, create out file in new directory
    if (os.path.isdir("recv")):
            os.chdir("recv")
            try:
                    outFile = open(inFile.name,"wb")
            except IOError:
                    print "something went wrong creating the out file"
                    sys.exit()
    else :
            os.mkdir("recv")
            os.chdir("recv")
            try:
                    outFile = open(inFile.name,"wb")
            except IOError:
                    print "something went wrong creating the out file"
                    sys.exit()

#loop to copy bytes to new directory
    fileSizeRemainingInBytes = os.path.getsize(inFile)
    print "Initial size: ", fileSizeRemainingInBytes
    while fileSizeRemainingInBytes > 0 :
            print fileSizeRemainingInBytes
            bytesToCopy = inFile.read(buffer);
            outFile.write(bytesToCopy);
    inFile.close()
```

Comment: This is the full output when I run it:  %python copy.py test.txt
file name is:  test.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "copy.py", line 42, in <module>
    fileSizeRemainingInBytes = os.path.getsize(inFile)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/genericpath.py", line 49, in getsize
    return os.stat(filename).st_size
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found

Answer (score 0):

`os.path.getsize` takes a file *path* as an argument, not a file object. So you actually want to call `os.path.getsize(inFile.name)`. Note that this won't give you the number of bytes remaining to copy; it'll just give you the size of the whole file every time it's evaluated. To get the number of bytes remaining, you'll have to keep track of the total number of bytes read and subtract this total from the file size.

Something like this should work:

```
import sys
import os

buffer = 1000

with open(sys.argv[1], "rb") as in_file:

    # Make your `recv` directory as a sub-directory
    # or your current directory if it doesn't already exist
    if not os.path.isdir("recv"):
        os.mkdir("recv")


    # Create the path to the file to which you 
    # want to copy. When opened, you'll have a file
    # with the same file name as your input file,
    # but it will be in your `recv` subdirectory
    out_file_path = os.path.join("recv", in_file.name)

    # Read the bytes
    with open(out_file_path, "wb") as out_file:
        bytes_read = 0 
        bytes_to_read = os.path.getsize(in_file.name)
        while bytes_read < bytes_to_read:
            out_file.write(in_file.read(buffer))
            bytes_read += min(buffer, bytes_to_read - bytes_read)
            print "{} / {} bytes copied".format(bytes_read, bytes_to_read)
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the issue. However, now it just returns a size of 0 even though I tried it on a fairly large jpeg file. Do you see why that might be?

Comment: Never mind, I got it working. I moved setting fileSizeRemainingInBytes to the top right under I set inFile. I don't understand why that worked though

Comment: It's because you changed directories, and then you created a new, empty file with the same name. So you were getting the size of the new file you created.